# Prevent wrapping of elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list of check boxes inside a div. I wanted to give the div a fixed width but I do not want the labels of these check boxes to go down 1 line. I also want to retain the scroll bars so the user can see the hidden parts if he wants to. Some say use `float:left;` or `overflow:hidden;` but this does not seem to work. I keep getting the list with the labels going down the line instead of being hidden. I thought `overflow:hidden;` would fix this but it instead expanded the width of my div to show the rest of the labels.

```
<div style='width:80;height:200;overflow:scroll;'>
<input type='checkbox' value='All'>All<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='San Francisco'>San Francisco<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='North Carolina'>North Carolina<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York<br>
</div>
```

[image]

Question is how can I give the div a fixed width but I do not want the labels of these check boxes to go down 1 line and I want to retain the scroll bars?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

not sure if this is what you want but try so:

```css
#list{
  width:80px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <input type='checkbox' value='All'>All
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='San Francisco'>San Francisco
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='North Carolina'>North Carolina
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad i helped.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following CSS to your page:

```
input
{
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use,

```
white-space: nowrap;
word-break: keep-all;
```

To prevent word wrapping.

e.g.

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type='checkbox' value='All'>All<br>
    <input type='checkbox' value='San Francisco'>San Francisco<br>
    <input type='checkbox' value='North Carolina'>North Carolina<br>
    <input type='checkbox' value='New York'>New York<br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.checkbox-wrapper {
    width:80px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a simple list

So use the proper markup!

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="All">All</li>
...
</ul>
```

Then style it with CSS:

```
ul { width: 80px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll; list-style-type: none;}
li { white-space: nowrap; }
```

The last part should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in two ways

1) increase the width of the div

2) use text-overflow

```css
div.testing {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
body {
  padding : 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style='width:80px;height:200px;overflow:scroll;'>
<div class="testing"><input type="checkbox" value='All'> All</div>
<div class="testing"><input type="checkbox" value='San Francisco'> San Francisco</div>
<div class="testing"><input type="checkbox" value='North Carolina'> North Carolina</div>
<div class="testing"><input type="checkbox" value='New York'> New York</div>
</div>
```